# Would a native say 心底から申し上げる? What's a better way to say "speaking with genuine sincerity...."

Tags: word-choice

I've always thought / said that "心底から申し上げる" means "I am saying this with highest level of sincerity (bottom of my heart)"

"心底から申し上げて、お詫びいたします。" *I very sorry for what I have done.*

Google search says "心底から申し上げる" is used only 650 times, which suggests 心底 and 申し上げる is very rare and not a natural pairing of words.

So, if I want to express that apologies, respect, love, condolences are coming from my "inner most thoughts", "bottom of my heart", "not superficial", is there a word to substitute for "心底"? Is it so context based on each emotion, it is on a case by case basis and there's no simple answer?

And, what impressions does "心底から申し上げて、お詫びいたします。" give?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 心底から申し上げて、お詫びいたします。

This is at least grammatical, but sounds like something awkward like "I put it honestly, and (then) I apologize" or "I apologize by saying it from the bottom of my heart".

The common expression is simply 心からお詫びを申し上げます. 心底から/心底より is probably not wrong, but it's much less common than 心から/心より.

Comment: あっ You beat me! また遅かったぁ・・

Answer (score 4):

心底から申し上げて、お詫びいたします。 sounds unnatural to me, I'm afraid.

I think I'd probably say...

> **[心]{こころ}より** / **心から**お詫び申し上げます。

Some other examples:

> 一日も早い復興を心よりお祈りいたします。
>   皆様のご健康とご多幸を心よりお祈りいたします。
>   心より感謝申し上げます。

Comment: How about 「深く」or「謹んで」？

Comment: @Halfway そうですね、両方使えると思います。「謹んで」 is more like "I humbly..." than "sincerely, from the bottom of my heart, deeply", though.